# Github How to rename user and repository name

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to rename/change the user and repo-name from a remote repository without changing its location? From for example:

```
git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

to

```
git@github.com:newuser/newrepo.git
```

if yes, how is this possible by using terminal?

Comment: Are you just asking how to switch remotes (in which case see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), or do you actually want to rename your GH account/repo name?

Comment: hmm yeah, maybe switching the remotes will work too - but basically I want to rename..

Comment: Then see e.g. https://help.github.com/en/articles/renaming-a-repository

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks alot!